# O(n) string handling in Scheme

Tags: scheme

**Background**: I've been writing a little interpreter in Scheme (R5RS).

The reader/lexer takes a (sometimes long) string from input and tokenises it. It does this by matching the first few characters of the string against some token and returning the token and the remaining unmatched part of the string.

**Problem**: to return the remaining portion of the string, a new string is created every time a token is read. This means the reader is O(n^2) in the number of tokens present in the string.

**Possible solution**: convert the string to a list, which can be done in time O(n), then pull tokens from the list instead of the string, returning the remainder of the list instead of the remainder of the string. But this seems terribly inefficient and artificial.

**Question**: am I imagining it, or is there just no other way to do this efficiently in Scheme due to its purely functional outlook?

Edit: in R5RS Scheme, there isn't a way to return a pointer into a string. The "substring" function is the only function which extracts an object which is itself a string. But the Scheme standard insists this be a newly allocated string. Why? Because strings are not immutable in Scheme R5RS, e.g. see the "string-set!" function!!

One solution suggested below which works is to store an index into the string. Then one can read off the characters one at a time from that index until a token is read. Too bad the regexp library I'm using for the tokenisation requires an actual string not an index into one...

Comment: This may not be related at all, but in a class I took, when we wrote an interpreter in Scheme, we used quoted lists rather than strings, as it makes things sooo much easier.  Example: '((print "foo") (my-syntax a "b" 12)) etc

Comment: some code might help to clarify. why do you claim that there are O(n^2) tokens present?

Comment: Honestly, my intuition would be that you ought to be treating the string as a list or vector the whole way through.  Anyway, though, in theory, this should be easier, not harder, given immutable strings (since the "cloned" string could share structure instead of actually copying anything.)  However, I don't know if this is implemented in any existing Scheme string type.  You didn't specify dialect.  I do know that Racket makes a distinction between immutable and mutable strings, so you might want to check out whether they have optimized this and/or the performance of their substring function.

Comment: @davin : there aren't O(n^2) tokens, there are n tokens by defn. I mean the time is O(n^2) because of the creation of a new string for each token that is removed.

Comment: @mquander: Racket is not really R5RS. I'm using Gambit (because I needed to compile to C). But plain R5RS scheme is what I am after. I'm not sure vectors help either. Seems to be the same problem as strings.

Comment: Well, if your string was an immutable vector with fast random access, you can just pass around a pair `(contents, index)` that represents a substring of `contents` starting from `index`; to cut a bit off the front, just increment `index`.  That avoids copying entirely.  Anyway, I don't know anything about Gambit libraries, sorry : (

Comment: if there are n tokens, and you create a string for each one, your time complexity is O(n), not sure where your quadratic came from

Comment: Re the immutable thing, I think you are right. This is not a problem with Scheme, but with the implementation. Of course it should be able to return a different "view" into the same string object! The Gambit libraries don't really help here. It also seemed that I should be able to do it with things defined in the R5RS Scheme standard, rather than rely on a non-standard library function.

Comment: @davin : the complexity seems to be coming from returning the unmatched part of the string, which still has n-1 tokens left in it. So to create this new string takes some constant times n-1 operations, as it has to copy out the remaining contents of the old string to make the new one.

Comment: that complexity analysis is totally implementation dependant, for example, as mquander mentioned, its not difficult to see how the string "creation" can be implemented in constant time by changing a vector size/index. i suppose youre left to you and your libraries...

Comment: I agree. But the Scheme standard is asking a lot of the implementation. It must store a string as a pointer into an array plus a length, otherwise any substring call *must* create a new string (what happens for me). Moreover, the gc has to recognise that there is still a pointer to the string, even though it points to some internal part of the string. What I really want to do is write such a function whose complexity does not depend on the Scheme implementation (assuming the Scheme is not completely stupid). Is going via lists the only fully R5RS solution which guarantees the complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Consider making a shared-substring implementation of strings (this is how Java does it, for example). So when you want to grab a substring of a given string, rather than copying the characters, simply keep a pointer to (some location in) those characters, and a length.

Comment: @Bill: The language itself, no. But when you're writing your own implementation, you can do anything you want!

Comment: @Chris: Ah, I think I see. You mean to store an index into the string. Sadly, the standard regexp library I'm using requires an actual string from which to pull the next token. An index into a string won't work. I'm gonna have to rewrite the regexp library basically.

Comment: @Bill: You can hack in a match start position at index *m* with `^.{m} ⟨actual-regex⟩`. I.e. "at start-of-string, match any character exactly *m* times, then match the actual regex."

Comment: @Bill: OMG, I misread your question, sorry! I thought you were writing an interpreter _for_ Scheme, not _in_ Scheme. Hmm, yes, that might cramp your space a little. Hopefully you can use (or switch to) a Scheme implementation that does do substring sharing.

Comment: @Cirno: nice idea, that *might* work, depending on how well the regex library is implemented. However, if it reads off the first m characters one at a time, then the time will still be O(n^2) overall.